# Why is this rsync not working?

Tags: bash, magento, rsync

I'm not having SSH access, only cronjob access.

I've written a copy.sh script in order to rsync the folders, but it does not happen. Why?

```
OLDDIR="/var/www/web46/html/magento-v2"
NEWDIR="/var/www/web46/html/magento-v4"
rsync -au $OLDDIR/media/ $NEWDIR/media >> log.txt
# rsync -au $OLDDIR/app/code/ $NEWDIR/app/code
# rsync -au $OLDDIR/app/design/ $NEWDIR/app/design 
# rsync -au $OLDDIR/app/etc/modules/ $NEWDIR/app/etc/modules 
# rsync -au $OLDDIR/app/locale/ $NEWDIR/app/locale
# rsync -au $OLDDIR/js/ $NEWDIR/js
# rsync -au $OLDDIR/skin/ $NEWDIR/skin
```

This is the target folder:

[image: magento-v2 folder]

This is the destination folder AFTER the script has run:

[image: magento-v4 folder]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest to use absolute paths with a leading `/` or first `cd` to directory with folder `magento-v2`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

For **any** shell script running from a cron:

1. Use full paths.  (Both in the script, and in the crontab referencing the script)
2. Ensure the script is made executable and that the correct user has permissions to run.  (see

Regarding **Magento:**

1. Make sure you use crontab syntax applicable to **magento**.
2. See this example setup from this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63717

   - ```
     */5 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -m=default
     */5 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -m=always
     ```
3. Consider posting your question in http://magento.stackexchange.com if these basic steps don't help.

**NOTE:** Most tutorials / help guides / help forums, will assume, rightly or wrongly, the default position that you are a **system admin**, given that you are troubleshooting an admin level task.  **Please specify** your exact constraints.

4. Refer to [Check your existing crontab](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html#check-your-existing-crontab)
   troubleshooting page

   > **Check your existing crontab**
   >
   > To verify whether or not your crontab is set up:
   >
   > Log in to your Magento server. As a user with root privileges, see if
   >   a crontab is already set up.
   >
   > `crontab -u <Magento file system owner name> -l`
   >
   > For example, on CentOS
   >
   > `crontab -u magento_user -l`
   >
   > If no crontab has been set up for the user,
   >   the following message displays:
   >
   > `no crontab for magento_user`
   >
   > See one of the following sections for a
   >   solution to your issue.
   >
   > Solution: crontab not set up
   >
   > To verify your cron jobs are set up properly, see [Set up cron jobs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron%22).
5. This sample script adds full paths and a shebang line to your rsync script.  **Note:** you may need to be able to test this outside of the cron to pinpoint the issue :

   - ```
     #!/bin/bash
     echo "At least I know the script ran up to here" > /var/log/myscriptran.log 
     OLDDIR="/usr/share/full-path/something/magento-v2"
     NEWDIR="/usr/share/full-path/something/magento-v4"
     /usr/bin/rsync -au "$OLDDIR/media/" "$NEWDIR/media" 2>> /var/log/rsync_cron.log
     ```

**Additionally**: If for some reason you need to run in the same environment, you can always add `source /User/your/home/folder/path/.profile` (replace with your applicable profile path).

**Crontab** runs in it's own environment, you need to assume it has no knowledge of you, your home folder, relative paths, your ssh certificates location, any common environment variables / settings that you may not even be aware of, etc.

What it will always understand is **full paths**, and it will execute, executable files, it has permission to run.

Comment: See my edit. I've included full paths, rsync hasn't worked. :(

Comment: you say you have no SSH access.  meaning you have no console / shell access at all ?  Just the magento web GUI ?

Comment: @Atr_Max You aren't giving a lot of information.  You say you have a "Target" folder and a "Destination" folder.  Are they different ?  Was the destination folder previously empty ?

Comment: There are some notes here recommending against running crontab as root or www on magento.  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: Yes, I only have Cron access, no shell access itself (like ssh or something, so I cannot debug very well here). Every folder is empty when you create it - in this case I've created the Dir by unzipping a .zip-file.

Comment: @Atr_Max I've given you some good resource which should point you in the right direction if these basic checks have not helped.  Magento has a heavy focus on cronjobs and runs a little differently between versions.  Permissions and user are an important consideration.

Comment: This is only for the magento-intern crons. I use the cron outside of magento, its not bound to it, and it should not make a difference if my target dir is a WP-Folder, a Magento folder or a 100% customized folder structure. Meanwhile I think its a bug with the hoster, since `cp` doesn't get executed as well anymore... Weird!

Comment: Turns out, I made a mistake with `cp`. `rsync` still not working correctly. :/

Comment: @Atr_Max is the cron executing at all ?  Can you make a simple script such as `echo "hello I have run from the cron" > /tmp/cronrun` and see if that file has been created with those contents ?  This is probably best debugged starting at this level

Comment: At hosters side, rsync wasn't enabled... Support said that it would work. Lol. Tried CP and came to success real quick. Thanks y'all.